# Statistical test for convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Please forgive my total ignorance on all things statistical. I have some sequence of distributions (actual data, a collection of real numbers for each positive integer, which don't appear to converge to a normal distribution or any other obvious distribution). Is there a recommended statistical test to give evidence that it's converging to anything at all? I can see that each of the moments appear to converge - is that enough?

Comment: why would you think they converge to normal? if you are thinking about the Central Limit Theorem, only the average of the random iid samples will converge to normal in distribution...

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't converge to normal, as the skew/3rd standardized moment doesn't appear to be converging to 0. The reason I would have expected it is a long story - basically, the random variable is not quite the average of random iids but the sum of random variables (one for each node in a graph) which are independent when the nodes are "far enough away"

Comment: interesting. if the random variables (from which your r.v. is a sum) are independent and identically distributed, the distribution of the sum will be normal as well...